# Delaying display of an image only works once

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I have a situation where I need to delay the displaying of a certain image on the page. The page is an image map of the U.S. When the user clicks on a state, a jQuery powered overlay open over the map to show that state's info.

The image in question here is inside that overlay, but its position is set to fixed so it won't scroll. It appears on top of the overlay before the overlay appears, which is why I'm delaying it a bit. That part works fine. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.scrollInst').fadeIn(500);
    }, 3000); 

    });
```

The problem is that when the user clicks the close (X) button on the overlay to close it, the delayed fade in of the image stops delaying and fading in. Every subsequent overlay that the user opens by clicking on another state on the map displays the image without the delay and fade in. In other words, it completely stops working and the image pops up first before the overlay which was the original problem I solved with the delay/fadeIn.

I need to find a way to 'reset' that div to it's original state so that when the user clicks the next state on the map and a new overlay pops up, the image is delayed and fades in like it did on the first overlay.

I tried adding fadeOut() and hide() to the close button thinking that it would reset that div, but that just make it not show the div ever again after clicking the close button.

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".overlay").hide("scale", 300, function(){
 $('.scrollInst').css('display','none');
});
```

Any ideas?

By the way... This is not a regular website. It's going to be displayed from a local copy loaded on a tablet. The browser being used (Dolphin) does not work with CSS transitions, so that's out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

A example of your code would be very helpful. However, I think I understand the issue. Here are some key points.

A. You don't need a setTimeout for the initial delay. jQuery has a built in "delay()" method.

```
$('.scrollInst').delay(300).fadeIn(500);
```

B. When you say "reset" the DIV, do you mean the HTML contents of the DIV or the CSS value of the div? HTML contents can be reset by:

```
$('.whatever-selector').html("");
```

CSS can be "reset" by simply changing the values with the "css()" method.

```
$('.whatever-selector').css({top: 0, left: 0, etc});
```

C. Overall I think your approach may be a little off. What should happen, is when you click on an element on the map, jQuery creates the overlay div, injects it into the DOM (opacity 0, so it isn't visible) and then uses Fade in to gracefully animate it into the page. On close, it should fade it out, and then empty the contents for the next overlay.

Hope that helps.